# Is it possible to read bits in a loop by determining the amount to read?

Tags: java, bit, datainputstream

There is a DataInputStream from which to read

I met a specific algorithm:

1. int[] nmbrs = new int[64];
2. Read a 4-bit unsigned integer. Assign Length the value read
3. for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)

   3.1 Read an Length-bit unsigned integer as nmbrs[i]

Is it possible to write in Java? How to write it?

Comment: Is "4. Repeat from point 1" support to mean "Repeat step 3.1", i.e. it is entirely redundant given the step 3 (the `for` loop) implies the exact same thing.

Comment: @Andreas It's another array. So I guess the question is how to do something twice.

Comment: *"how to do something twice"* Put the logic in a method and cal it twice: `int[] nmbrs = readNumbers(dataStream); int[] nmbrs = readNumbers(dataStream);`

Comment: So if the first 4 bits (the `Length` value) is the number 3, you then read 64 x 3 = 192 bits into `nmbrs`, so a total of 4 + 192 = 196 bits, aka 24.5 bytes, will be read from the stream. Does that mean that the `Length` value of `nmbrs2` is in the second half of that last byte? So if it is also the value 3, you will be consuming a total of 24.5 + 24.5 = 49 bytes from the input stream?

Comment: in step 4, i just need to have the source ready for the next reading. The question is more about 2, 3, 3.1

Comment: As a shameless plug, I created a library that might be able to help you: https://github.com/jhg023/BitBuffer

Comment: But `DataInputStream` reads full bytes (or more). You cannot read individual bits, so if `nmbrs` doesn't consume a multiple of full bytes (see my previous comment), then you cannot just repeat the operation on the `DataInputStream`, or you'd lose the unused bits in the last byte processed.

Comment: @JacobG. Won't work, because OP's code doesn't know the full size up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BitInputStream` class that reads bits from the underlying `DataInputStream`.

Like this:

```
public final class BitInputStream implements Closeable {

    private final InputStream in;
    private final ByteOrder streamBitOrder;
    private int bits;
    private byte bitsLeft;

    public BitInputStream(InputStream in) {
        this(in, ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    }

    public BitInputStream(InputStream in, ByteOrder bitOrder) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(in);
        Objects.requireNonNull(bitOrder);
        this.in = in;
        this.streamBitOrder = bitOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.in.close();
    }

    public int readBit() throws IOException {
        if (this.bitsLeft == 0) {
            if ((this.bits = this.in.read()) == -1)
                throw new EOFException();
            this.bitsLeft = 8;
        }
        int bitIdx = (this.streamBitOrder == ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN ? this.bitsLeft - 1 : 8 - this.bitsLeft);
        this.bitsLeft--;
        return (this.bits >> bitIdx) & 1;
    }

    public int readInt() throws IOException {
        return readInt(Integer.SIZE, this.streamBitOrder);
    }

    public int readInt(ByteOrder bitOrder) throws IOException {
        return readInt(Integer.SIZE, bitOrder);
    }

    public int readInt(int len) throws IOException {
        return readInt(len, this.streamBitOrder);
    }

    public int readInt(int len, ByteOrder bitOrder) throws IOException {
        if (len == 0)
            return 0;
        if (len < 0 || len > Integer.SIZE)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid len: " + len + " (must be 0-" + Integer.SIZE + ")");
        int value = 0;
        if (bitOrder == ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                value = (value << 1) | readBit();
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                value |= readBit() << i;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String bitData = "0101 00001 00001 00010 00011 00101 01000 01101 10101" // 5: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
                  + " 0011 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111";                // 3: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(bitData.replaceAll(" ", ""), 2);
    System.out.println("0x" + bi.toString(16) + " = 0b" + bi.toString(2));
    byte[] byteData = bi.toByteArray();
    try (BitInputStream in = new BitInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteData))) {
        int[] nmbrs = readNmbrs(in);
        int[] nmbrs2 = readNmbrs(in);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nmbrs));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nmbrs2));
    }
}
private static int[] readNmbrs(BitInputStream in) throws IOException {
    int[] nmbrs = new int[8];
    int length = in.readInt(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < nmbrs.length; i++)
        nmbrs[i] = in.readInt(length);
    return nmbrs;
}
```

*Output*

```
0x5084432a1b53053977 = 0b10100001000010001000011001010100001101101010011000001010011100101110111
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I want to additionally ask about ByteOrder. The value `LITTLE_ENDIAN` means that 0b1010100100001111 will be read as 0b1111000010010101 = 0xf095, not 0x0fa9

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to write in Java? How to write it?

Java provides no mechanism for performing I/O in units smaller than one byte, but you can implement it on top of byte-oriented I/O.  You would need to buffer one or more bytes at a time while you read, and track a bit-level position within that buffer.

Note also that this is sensitive to (logical) bit-order questions -- i.e. do you read out bits from most- to least-significant or the other way around?

Comment: I'm a little nervous about the finish point. What if it is not a multiple of 8?

Comment: That's a function of your protocol, @Shklyar.  The sending end is operating under the same per-byte I/O constraints as the receiving end, so you need to know what it does at the end of the bit stream.  But note that finishing step 3 / 3.1 does not necessarily mean that you're at the end of the bit stream.